# When is it necessary to use singleTop launchMode in an android widget or application?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-searchmanager

I just got burned by a widget.  I could see the cause of the problem, but I could not determine why or its solution.  My widget was issuing a search (SearchManager) and the activity launched a search dialog, but when it called-back to my widget, it created another reference to the widget (i.e., the thread-id was the same, but the widget-id changed from 65 to 0).

This led me to believe that a new instance was getting created and I searched the documentation for settings that would apply to the problem.  Eventually, I stumbled upon the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and as soon as I set it in the AndroidManifest, viola!  My widget worked.

This took me the better part of two days to debug.

Are there any other situations or is there a more technically-correct answer to my problem?

Comment: I don't think the question title is useful for the contents. I'd hoped to see a question and answers about appropriate use cases for singleTop. This is a bit of development narrative and then a quote from the documentation.

Comment: @Lot105 - fair enough.  Go ahead and add some answers.  It was a huge problem that I encountered so I did the "ask and answer your own question" as is suggested by SO.  I am certain that your answer contribution(s) and others would improve this Q&A.  It has had over 3000 views, so there is clearly interest.  I doubt that my answer is the *ONLY* answer :)  And of course, it is a reference and quote from the doc since that is where I got my answer.  Personally, I find real value in this style issue / answer as it clarifies DOC.

Comment: I should have been clearer. The question body and answer are useful and interesting in their own right, absolutely.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I did more reading in Android Docs -- I could spend a lifetime reading their docs and find a new subtle detail that breaks my brain :)  This explains my multiple-instances that I did not expect, however, I configured to occur.

[Android Doc on Activity definition for AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes
>   differ from each other in just one
>   respect: Every time there's new intent
>   for a "standard" activity, a new
>   instance of the class is created to
>   respond to that intent. Each instance
>   handles a single intent. Similarly, a
>   new instance of a "singleTop" activity
>   may also be created to handle a new
>   intent. However, if the target task
>   already has an existing instance of
>   the activity at the top of its stack,
>   that instance will receive the new
>   intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a
>   new instance is not created. In other
>   circumstances — for example, if an
>   existing instance of the "singleTop"
>   activity is in the target task, but
>   not at the top of the stack, or if
>   it's at the top of a stack, but not in
>   the target task — a new instance would
>   be created and pushed on the stack.

Comment: "or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack." Why? Can someone explain this quoted section further?

Comment: @Patrick I believe this scenario is when you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. In this case, you don't care about existing task, and you are creating a new task, so your activity becomes the only one in the new task. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Gokhan Arik I don't think that's correct. This is the documentation for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: "When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK for a flag to disable this behavior." So you see that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK does not create necessarily create a new task - only if necessary. Otherwise it reuses the existing task.