# Android: resume app from previous position

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I resume my app from its previous position.

Note that it is still active, just paused. So if I click the androids current app button, or the app icon it resumes fine.

But who do I do this from my widget..

I have the following:

```
// Create an Intent to launch Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginForm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

This obviously launches the LoginForm as opposed to just resuming the application.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit:

Just to clarify, I dont want anything special. I basically want to mimic pressing the android icon launcher.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268962/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-single-top-launchmode-in-an-android-widget-or-applic) SO question (possible duplicate)

Comment: Please don't try to mess with launch modes to make this work. It isn't necessary and creates more trouble later on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question ;-)

Just simulate what Android does when you launch the app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginForm.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

or you could try this (assuming `LoginForm` is the root activity of your application and that there is an instance of this activity still active in the task stack):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginForm.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` **should** just bring an exising task for the application from the background to the foreground without actually creating an instance of the activity. Try this first. If it doesn't work for you, do the other.

Comment: Headache gone. Thanks man! :) It now resumes at what ever activity it was last left at :)

Comment: The ACTION_MAIN solution will not work on every device. Just tested that no samsung device supports it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this it is same as android doing for your launcher activity

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent clickActionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Should be `PendingIntente.getActivity`?