# how to avoid click on android shortcut create new app instance and kill the old one

Tags: android, shortcut, launchmode

I have create a android shortcut via the following code

```
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");                    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,getString(R.string.app_name));  
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setClassName(this,MainActivity.class.getName());
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    shortcut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);
    sendBroadcast(shortcut);
```

when i open my app and finally in some Activity like BActivity,then i switch to home screen and click the shortcut , the app come to MainActivity as the code above , can i have a chance to avoid this and just let the app come in foreground if it's already created ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303663/android-resume-app-from-previous-position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find the correct way to do this, in one word this is a bug in android and a workaround may be following

```
if(!isTaskRoot()){
    finish();
    return;
}
```

add the code above in your LaucherClass's onCreate