# In android, how to start a new activity unless another instance is running, then instead activate the old on?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

In essence my app will have 4 activities.  A,B,C,D.
A goes to C
A-->C

where C might want to go to D, back to C, back to D.  Or anywhere within this path.
B <--> C <---> D

I have reason to believe this is spawning a new activity each time, which is resulting in multiple stacks of the same activity.  For instance moving back and forth between C and D 3x would result in 3 live activities for C and 3 for D.

The question is how can I accomplish this to where if a new activity needs to be created it will, yet if one has already been created, it will move to displaying the previous spawn.  C(1)-->D(1)-->C(1)
instead of 
C(1)-->D(1)-->C(2)

Or even more simply what if I wanted to go back and forth between A and B with buttons but not create an ever increasing stack of instances?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. Please see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283118/1369222

Comment: I tried this and it has made zero effect.  I used 
    Intent i = new     Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       startActivity(i);
At every point where the activities are started.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

where you can flag your activity to launch only a single instance or a new task