# Launch singleTop Activity from another Task

Tags: android

I have some trouble with understanding of **singleTop** flag with launching Activity.

In my app i have 2 tasks :

```
Task 1 : A,B,C,D

Task 2 : X,Y,Z
```

All activities is a **"standard"** *mode* for launch except **Activity D** - she has **"singleTop"**.

Both tasks is running.

**Task1 [A,B,C,D]**
**Task2 [X,Y,Z]**

Now is Z activity is opened. How will looks my stack if i run activity **D** from activity **Z**?

Comment: Take look on this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268962/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-singletop-launchmode-in-an-android-widget-or-applica

Comment: @mohammedmomn so my Task2 will have a stack XYZD ?

Comment: How do you have 2 tasks? Why do you have 2 tasks? I hope you realize that having multiple tasks in your application creates a lot of problems with navigation. Also, if the user goes to the recent tasks list, will they be able to navigate back to each of your tasks?

Comment: @DavidWasser 2 tasks it means that 2 apps in different tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are actually 2 different applications (as you stated in your comment) and activity D has no specific `android:taskAffinity` defined in the manifest, then the following will happen:

- If Activity Z launches Activity D without any special Intent flags, a new instance of Activity D will be launched into Task 2, so that the Activity stack in Task 2 will contain [X,Y,Z,D]
- If Activity Z launches Activity D and sets `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching it, Task 2 will go to the background, Task 1 will be brought to the foreground, `onNewIntent()` will be called on the existing instance of Activity D in Task 1 and then `onResume()` will be called on the existing instance of Activity D in Task 1. A new instance of Activity D will not be created.