# My app doesn't resume from the current activity but restart from the launcher activity every time it's put in Background . What to do to fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I hope you're doing great. Please, I need help for an issue.
I'm working on an app that has three activities : **StartActivity**, **MainActivity** and **SettingActivity**. The **StartActvity** is the launcher activity and the **MainActivity** has **NavHostFragment** with four **fragments**. When I launch the app for the first time, it navigates to the **MainActivity** after some delay; that is one of expected behaviors. Now when, the app navigate to **MainActivity**, it doesn't resume from it's current state in **MainActivity** when it's put in **background**. It restarts from **StartActivity** every time I put it in **Background** after interacting with **fragments** and all the actions are lost. For example, if I start **searching something with SearchView in a fragment and put the app in background, it loses what I was doing and restart from StartActivity instead of resuming from  MainActivity**. I've tried some solutions but it doesn't work.

Here are my **activities** codes :

**StartActivity**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)

        if (!isTaskRoot){
            finish()
            return
        }

        Handler().postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }, 1800)

    }

}
```

Here, I first used **finish()** in the **intent** and as it didn't work, I added the code that is in **if statement**

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, binding.drawerLayout)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, binding.drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

}
```

**My manifest content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="eg.esperantgada.dailytodo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.TodoApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DailyToDo"
        tools:ignore="DataExtractionRules">

        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />

        <receiver android:name=".broadcastreceiver.TodoAlarmReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If anyone can help me to fix it, I'll be very glad. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue comes from `android:noHistory="true"`. I've added it when fixing another issue and forgotten to remove it. Now after removing it, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete       `android:launchMode="singleTop"` from your StartActivity tag in the manifest file it should be all done.

You can read more about singletop in this stackOverFlow solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283118/6565331

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your answer. I think the problem comes from ```android:noHistory="true"```. When I removed it, it worked . Thank you